# Enable suggestions for Chrome omnibox and custom search engines?

Tags: google-chrome

I live in Canada and my default search engine is google.ca. I want all searches to be google.com, so I'm using this as my default search engine:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}`

I copied most of this from Chrome's default search engine, which is this:

`{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}`

However, I can't get suggestions for my custom search engine. To clarify, by "suggestions", I mean getting a list of search queries that I never searched before. How do I enable suggestions for custom search engines?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by editing `last_known_google_url` in the preferences file. Then, I switched back to the default search engine. It now defaults to google.com.